# Sort DynamoDB data scan using Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a table in DynamoDB and the primary key is a number stored as string. When I use the GetItem of DynamoClient, the order of items is random.

[image: My code snippet]

Here is my Lambda function;

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // Bring in the documentClient library
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 

    // instanialize 
    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    // extract variables that we need to use in db
    // const { country, visits } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const params = {
        TableName: "age_distribution"
    };

    try {
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise(); 
        // add data into the db
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items); 
        // hold the response in a string type
        statusCode = 200;
    } catch (err) {
        responseBody = `Unable to get record: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : " application/json",
            "access-control-allow-origin" : "*"
        },
        body: responseBody 
        //send back the responseBody
    };

    // return the response
    return response;
};
```

this is the sample response

```
[{"country":"63","visits":3},{"country":"92","visits":4},{"country":"64","visits":3},{"country":"90","visits":5},{"country":"79","visits":11},{"country":"66","visits":10},{"country":"80","visits":20},{"country":"62","visits":4},{"country":"87","visits":6},{"country":"75","visits":22},{"country":"76","visits":16},{"country":"97","visits":1},{"country":"84","visits":13},{"country":"60","visits":2},{"country":"61","visits":4},{"country":"89","visits":7},{"country":"94","visits":1},{"country":"98","visits":1},{"country":"82","visits":17},{"country":"77","visits":16},{"country":"91","visits":4},{"country":"81","visits":18},{"country":"88","visits":10},{"country":"96","visits":1},{"country":"71","visits":18},{"country":"95","visits":1},{"country":"78","visits":21},{"country":"83","visits":12},{"country":"68","visits":14},{"country":"65","visits":6},{"country":"70","visits":12},{"country":"85","visits":9},{"country":"69","visits":13},{"country":"74","visits":12},{"country":"93","visits":3},{"country":"86","visits":10},{"country":"67","visits":6},{"country":"72","visits":11},{"country":"73","visits":26}]
```

I want to sort the items, starting with 60 and ending at 98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting in DynamoDb is done against the sort key value of the index

[From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false

So what you might want to do is create a GSI (global secondary index) with a sort key (range) that makes sense for you I often use timestamp like in this index definition:

```
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: productKey-timestamp-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: productKey
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
```

Then when I query this index I get the data ascending series against the timestamp.

If I want it in descending, then I use the following query:

```
 let params = {
        TableName: ORDERS_TABLE,
        Limit: 10,
        IndexName: 'productKey-timestamp-index',
        Key: {
            "productKey": productKey
        },
        KeyConditionExpression: 'productKey= :productKey',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':productKey': productKey
        },
        ScanIndexForward: false
    };

    db.query(params).then(console.log)
```

*Note: setting the `ScanIndexForward: false` reverses the order by the sort key i.e. `timestamp` in this case*